# How do I multiply these cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm constantly messing up multiplying cycles.
Consider (23)(12)(32). I keep doing 3->2->3 and getting (32). However, the correct answer appears to be (3,1). When do you stop? Once you hit a 1? I stopped at 3 because then it just restarts the cycles.

Comment: The product of cycles is a composition of functions. You plug an element into the right and then apply the cycles one by one. So if you start with 3, (32) makes this a 2, then what does (12) do the 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's apply this permutation to the number $3.$ I'll write it like this: $$(23)(12)(32)\cdot 3.$$ The first cycle (i.e. the rightmost cycle) sends $3$ to $2,$ so we have $$(23)(12)(32)\cdot 3 = (23)(12)\cdot 2.$$ We then again apply the rightmost cycle in the new expression and see that $2$ gets sent to $1,$ so $$(23)(12)\cdot 2 = (23)\cdot 1.$$ Finally, the cycle $(23)$ fixes the number $1,$ so $(23)\cdot 1 = 1.$ Putting this all together we find that $$(23)(12)(32)\cdot 3 = 1.$$ We similarly get that $$(23)(12)(32)\cdot 1 = 3$$ and $$(23)(12)(32)\cdot 2 = 2.$$ So this new permuation swaps $1$ and $3$ and fixes $2,$ which is the permutation which we denote by $(13).$

Comment: Thanks - big help!